# One Dimensional Wave Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Prove that if $L(u)=0$ and $L(v)=0$ then 
$$
L(u_tv_t+c^2u_xv_x)=0.
$$
Where $L$ is defined by 
$$
L(u)=u_{tt}-c^2u_{xx}=0.
$$

I don't know how I would arrive to the conclusion. 
I have gotten close such that since $v=u=0$ then we can do 
$$
L(u)*L(v) = u_tv_t+c^2u_xv_x - cv_tu_x - cu_tv_x
$$

Thank you

Comment: Thanks for fixing that @chinny84. should have known it was latex coding.

Comment: So if $u,v$ satisfy the wave equation, applying $L$ to $u_{tt}-c^2 u_{xx}$ means you need to evaluate
\begin{align}
L(u_{t}v_{t}-c^{2} u_{x}v_{x}) &= (u_{t}v_{t}-c^{2} u_{x}v_{x})_{tt}-c^{2}(u_{t}v_{t}-c^{2} u_{x}v_{x})_{xx} \\
\end{align}

Comment: How would i evaluate that?

Comment: After a few attempts using the product rule, you'll find that you can use the fact that both $L(u),L(v)$ vanish and things will begin to cancel. It may be long winded but it's a good exercise in the product rule, if nothing else!

Comment: For example $(u_t v_t)_{tt} = (u_{tt}v_{t}+u_{t}v_{tt})_{t}= \ldots$ and soon the wave equations on both $u,v$ are present

Comment: ahh okay i understand. I will try that and see if i come up with that solution

Comment: @Tilly - Everyone gets one edit from me! :)

Comment: @Tilly How did you do Tilly, all good?